# ImportError with VirtualEnv

Tags: python, virtualenv, importerror, python-import

I'm trying to use VirtualEnv for a Flask app that I'm creating since everyone has recommended me to do so.  After creating my virtual environment, I installed the libraries that I needed using pip while the environment was activated.  I'm running into ImportError problems with this script.  The code works fine when I'm not in the virtual environment.

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sc2reader
...
...
```

When I try to run it I get this:

```
(flaskapp)xxxx@xxxx-VirtualBox:~/flaskapp/bin$ ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sc2reader
ImportError: No module named sc2reader
```

I've tried changing the shebang to reflect my VirtualEnv path for Python, but that didn't fix anything.  The library is found in my `site-packages` folder in my virtual environment, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the ImportError.

I've never used VirtualEnv before so I'm assuming I configured it wrong so it's not seeing my site-packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the shebang.
If that does not work, try seeing what is the output of `which python`.